# Jquery if returns always false

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, onclick

So I have 2 problems here

1. The if which checks this `$isitchecked = $('#group' + groupnumber).hasClass("checked");` returns always false even though the class has the class "checked"
2. even though the groupnumber icrements it still works just with the first group.

```js
            var progressProcent = 0;
            var groupnumber = 1;

        $('#group' + groupnumber + ' input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

         $whatgroup = "#group" + groupnumber;

         $isitchecked = $('#group' + groupnumber).hasClass("checked");

          if ($isitchecked) {

          }else{
            progressProcent = progressProcent + 2.27272727;
          }

            $("#progress-container").removeClass("hide");
            $( $whatgroup).addClass("checked");

            $("#progress-bar").css('width', progressProcent + '%');

          groupnumber = groupnumber + 1;

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="question form-group">
          <h3>Question 1</h3>
          <fieldset class="test-field pull-left" id="group1">
            <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option1" class="left" value="-3">

            <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option2" class="left" value="-2">

            <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option3" class="left" value="-1">

            <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1neotral1" value="0">

            <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option1r" class="right" value="1">

            <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option2r" class="right" value="2">

            <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option3r" class="right" value="3">
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="question form-group">
          <h3>Question 2</h3>
          <fieldset class="test-field pull-left" id="group2">
            <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option1" class="left" value="-3">

            <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option2" class="left" value="-2">

            <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option3" class="left" value="-1">

            <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2neotral1" value="0">

            <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option1r" class="right" value="1">

            <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option2r" class="right" value="2">

            <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option3r" class="right" value="3">
          </fieldset>
        </div>
         <br />
         <br />
        <div class="progress-container" id="progress-container">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Forget about your jQuery code. What exactly you want to achieve, can you explain that?(explain in question)

Comment: You only ever hook the `click` event on `#group1 input[type="radio"]`, not on any other element.

Comment: whenever I answer a question with are 44, the progress bar should move or added 2.27272727, but if I change my mind about one question, the progress bard should not add anything because i already checked (answered) that block. does that make sense?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, but if I add a console.log behing the click function it inrements. so from #group1 to #group2 etc., but it still does not work

Comment: Right -- because you're not hooking up any handler on those other elements. You're calling `click` (hooking up the handler) **once**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do:-

```js
progressProcent = 0;
$("input[type='radio']").on('click',function(){
   if($(this).parent().find('.checked').length ==0){
      progressProcent = progressProcent + 2.27272727;
      $("#progress-bar").css('width', progressProcent + '%');
   } 
   $(this).addClass('checked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="question form-group">
  <h3>Question 1</h3>
  <fieldset class="test-field pull-left" id="group1">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option1" class="left" value="-3">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option2" class="left" value="-2">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option3" class="left" value="-1">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1neotral1" value="0">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option1r" class="right" value="1">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option2r" class="right" value="2">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option3r" class="right" value="3">
  </fieldset>
</div>
<br>
<div class="question form-group">
  <h3>Question 2</h3>
  <fieldset class="test-field pull-left" id="group2">
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option1" class="left" value="-3">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option2" class="left" value="-2">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option3" class="left" value="-1">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2neotral1" value="0">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option1r" class="right" value="1">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option2r" class="right" value="2">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option3r" class="right" value="3">
  </fieldset>
</div>
 <br />
 <br />
<div class="progress-container" id="progress-container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Explanation:-***

on click of radio button:-

1.First check that it's parent div have any radio button with `checked` class or not?

2.If no then do the addition+progress-bar increase and after that add the `checked` class to the clicked radio button.

3.2nd step will insure that next time when other radio button of the same div will clicked.Nothing will happen.

Answer (score 2):

```
var groupnumber = 1;
$('#group' + groupnumber + ' input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
```

is same as

```
$('#group1 input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

groupnumber = groupnumber + 1;// doesn't do anything??
```

This just binds click event to radio buttons in `group1`

---

Even if you implement it by correcting above issue, you cannot guarantee if user does select in the order group1, group2, group3.

---

Even when you need a reference to the parent group, it is better to get it relatively, rather than using the group numbers

```
$isitchecked = $('#group' + groupnumber).hasClass("checked");
```

can be something like

```
$isitchecked = $(this).parent().hasClass("checked");
```

But again, jQuery has [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector built-in and there is no need to implement it again and can cause edge cases and errors.

---

Here is a different approach to the problem.

[Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) used in `[id^="group"]`

```
$('fieldset[id^="group"] input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
// click event on all fields with id starting with group
  var checked = $("input[type='radio']:checked").length;
  // get number of radio button checked
  var total = $('fieldset[id^="group"]').length;
  // get total number of field sets
  var percent = checked/total*100;
  $("#progress-bar").css('width', percent + '%');
});
```

```js
$('[id^="group"] input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  var checked = $("input[type='radio']:checked").length;
  var total = $('fieldset[id^="group"]').length;
  var percent = checked/total*100;
  $("#progress-bar").css('width', percent + '%');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="question form-group">
  <h3>Question 1</h3>
  <fieldset class="test-field pull-left" id="group1">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option1" class="left" value="-3">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option2" class="left" value="-2">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option3" class="left" value="-1">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1neotral1" value="0">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option1r" class="right" value="1">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option2r" class="right" value="2">

    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option3r" class="right" value="3">
  </fieldset>
</div>
<br>
<div class="question form-group">
  <h3>Question 2</h3>
  <fieldset class="test-field pull-left" id="group2">
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option1" class="left" value="-3">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option2" class="left" value="-2">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option3" class="left" value="-1">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2neotral1" value="0">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option1r" class="right" value="1">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option2r" class="right" value="2">

    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option3r" class="right" value="3">
  </fieldset>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="progress-container" id="progress-container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is executed first

```
$isitchecked = $('#group' + groupnumber).hasClass("checked");
```

and then you're adding the class "checked"

```
$( $whatgroup).addClass("checked");
```

This is why it always returns false.

Also, you don't have to use increment logic, you could use this to find out the radio which was clicked.

Comment: I have to add the class after the if statement, other-vice the thing doesn't work at all. but good point, thanks

Comment: Use condition based the checked attribute instead of class as sabithpocker mentioned in his answer

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the click event you increase `groupnumber` by one. It makes a future click check for a different id, thats why you always get false.

Based on what I believe you want to achieve, you should do something like this (I tried to change your code at minimum):

```js
var progressProcent = 0;

// Selects all inputs inside the fieldsets (since all of them
// have the .test-field class)

$('.test-field input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    
    // Gets the closest fieldset
    $whatgroup = $(this).closest('.test-field');
    
    $isitchecked = $whatgroup.hasClass("checked");
    
    if ($isitchecked) {
        
    }else{
        progressProcent = progressProcent + 2.27272727;
    }
    
    $("#progress-container").removeClass("hide");
    $whatgroup.addClass("checked");
    
    $("#progress-bar").css('width', progressProcent + '%');   
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="question form-group">
    <h3>Question 1</h3>
    <fieldset class="test-field pull-left" id="group1">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option1" class="left" value="-3">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option2" class="left" value="-2">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option3" class="left" value="-1">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1neotral1" value="0">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option1r" class="right" value="1">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option2r" class="right" value="2">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1option3r" class="right" value="3">
    </fieldset>
</div>
<br>
<div class="question form-group">
    <h3>Question 2</h3>
    <fieldset class="test-field pull-left" id="group2">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option1" class="left" value="-3">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option2" class="left" value="-2">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option3" class="left" value="-1">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2neotral1" value="0">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option1r" class="right" value="1">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option2r" class="right" value="2">
        
        <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2option3r" class="right" value="3">
    </fieldset>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="progress-container" id="progress-container">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the jQuery part somewhat, should be pretty self-explanatory.
In general: don't use the same `id` for multiple elements; numbers appended or not. I cannot think of a single situation where that is required or not messy.

```js
var progressProcent = 0.0;
var questions = [];
var $questions;

function updateProgress(add) {
  if (add) progressProcent += 100 / $questions.length;
  $("#progress-container").removeClass("hide");
  $("#progress-bar").css('width', progressProcent + '%');
}

$(function() {
  $questions = $('.question');
  $questions.each(function(i) {
    $fieldset = $(this).find('fieldset');
    for (var v = -3; v <= 3; v++) {
      var theClass = v !== 0 ? (v < 0 ? "left" : "right") : null;
      var $input = $('<input>').attr("type", "radio").val(v).addClass(theClass).on('change', function() {
        if (!questions[i]) updateProgress(true);
        questions[i] = Number($(this).val());
        console.log(questions);
      });
      $fieldset.append($input);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset input.left {
  margin-right: 5px
}

fieldset input.right {
  margin-left: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="question form-group">
  <h3>Question 1</h3>
  <fieldset class="test-field pull-left" id="group1">
  </fieldset>
</div>
<br>
<div class="question form-group">
  <h3>Question 2</h3>
  <fieldset class="test-field pull-left" id="group2">
  </fieldset>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="progress-container" id="progress-container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'll also recommend to auto-generate the inputs for your questions; if you find yourself copy-pasting lots of code, then changing numbers around, you're again almost guaranteed to do it wrong.